# Force matlab gui to update ui control mid-function

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a gui using GUIDE in MATLAB, and from what I've read it looks like MATLAB updates the UI controls based on a timer every so often. Is there a way to force it to update the UI controls, so I can make it update in the middle of the function? Right now I have a function that does, simplifed, something like

```
set(handles.lblStatus,'String','Processing...')
%function that takes a long time
set(handles.lblStatus,'String','Done')
```

Since MATLAB doesn't update the GUI during a Callback function, the user only ever sees 'Done' after a long period of waiting and never sees 'Processing'. I tried adding `guidata(hObject, handles)` after the first set, hoping it would force the screen to update, but it doesn't.

Comment: It is not a timer but another thread (EDT) which updates UI http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try calling [DRAWNOW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html).

```
set(handles.lblStatus,'String','Processing...')
drawnow
%function that takes a long time
set(handles.lblStatus,'String','Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a [drawnow](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) function in matlab.

> `drawnow` completes pending drawing events

Comment: I have never quite really understood why people duplicate the information in previous answers as new answers.

Comment: I think it's fine if you give a better description, or more examples, or more links, or they're within a couple minutes so maybe it wasn't there when you're loading the page, but it's not fine when it's 10 minutes later and worse.

Comment: Yeah, something else needed my attention while I was answering. Sorry for being late